# How to save CSV file from within Java application

Tags: excel, csv

All I need to do from a Java application is to open a CSV file, and just save it. This CSV file is a template, and it has already been configured such that once you save it, it is updated with data. In my application, I have already generated the data, and all I need to do now is to open the template file and just hit save. Equivalent to opening up the Excel GUI and clicking File->Save. How can I do this from my Java Application?

Comment: change the `File.setLastModified()`. It will appear as if it had been saved. (don't really understand what you mean by configuring a CSV file, but still.)

Comment: what parameter would I need to send to setLastModified()?

Comment: read the doc, it is quite explicit.